# error when I do GET request from google using sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, web, get

I am a beginner in `Socket programming in python`. This is the first exercise I tried,but I get `403 forbidden error`. can someone point out why this error comes and how to fix it?

```
>>> streams = [info for info in socket.getaddrinfo('google.com','http') if info[1]==socket.SOCK_STREAM]
>>> info=streams[0]
>>> google_socket=socket.socket(*info[:3])
>>> google_socket.connect(info[-1])
>>> msg="GET /HTTP/1.1\r\n"
>>> msg
'GET /HTTP/1.1\r\n'
>>> msg+="Host: google.com\r\n\r\n"
>>> google_socket.sendall(msg)
>>> buffsize=4096
>>> response=""
>>> done=False
>>> while not done:
...    msg_part=google_socket.recv(buffsize)
...    if len(msg_part)<buffsize:
...       done=True
...       google_socket.close()
...    response+=msg_part
... 
>>> len(response)
1372
>>> response
'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\nContent-Length: 1201\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nDate: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 03:39:14 GMT\r\nServer: GFE/2.0\r\nAlternate-Protocol: 80:quic\r\n\r\n<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>G</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#f3c518 size=10>o</font><font face=times color=#0039b6 size=10>g</font><font face=times color=#30a72f size=10>l</font><font face=times color=#c41200 size=10>e</font></b></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;"><h1>We\'re sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\'t process your request right now.</p></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;">See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">&copy; 2013 Google - <a href="https://www.google.com">Google Home</a></div></body></html>'
>>> streams
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.33', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.41', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.32', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.34', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.35', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.36', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.37', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.38', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.39', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.40', 80)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('173.194.33.46', 80)), (30, 1, 6, '', ('2607:f8b0:400a:804::1002', 80, 0, 0))]
```

Thanks

Comment: The error seems to call you out `...but your computer or network may be sending automated queries...`

Comment: This is a 403 error not a 404

Comment: The error also has [a link to Google Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640) right in the error message. Did you try reading that?

Comment: Anyway, if you do read the error and the help, it will tell you that what you're trying to do is explicitly against Google's Terms of Service. The 403 error is a way of preventing you from accidentally violating that ToS. It might not be too hard to get around—but in that case you'd be _intentionally_ violating the ToS, and circumventing their reasonable countermeasures, which probably isn't something you want to do.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for pointing this. But do all servers give `403 forbidden`. I just want to see something working! so that I could learn

Comment: No, not all servers give 403 forbidden. You could try http://example.com. But the best thing to do is probably to set up a local web server (just [`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer) if you don't know how to set one up otherwise), and then hit that server from your code (`http://localhost:8000` if you used `SimpleHTTPServer`).

Comment: Nah, the best thing to do is to use http://httpbin.org/. It provides all sorts of test pages and explicit permission to use them. Best of all, somebody else maintains it, so you don't have to put up a local web server.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly specified the HTTP GET request. Try this:

```
>>> msg="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

Note the space between `/` and `HTTP`.